Indexing sheets in an Excel spreadsheet using a VB
I have 24 sheets - all with unique names - how can I create an indexer.
cursht = "Sheet Name 1"  
emptycount = 1
testcount = 0
tempcount = 0
 
Do
    tempcount = tempcount + 1
    If Sheets(cursht).Cells(1, tempcount) <> "" Then
        testcount = testcount + 1
    Else
        Sheets(cursht).Columns(tempcount).Delete
        emptycount = emptycount + 1
        tempcount = tempcount - 1
    End If
Loop Until emptycount = 30

Sheets(cursht).Columns(tempcount - 1).Copy Sheets(1).Columns(qccolcnt)
qccolcnt = qccolcnt + 1
Sheets(cursht).Columns(tempcount).Copy Sheets(1).Columns(qccolcnt)
qccolcnt = qccolcnt + 1

cursht = "Sheet Name 2"
emptycount = 1
testcount = 0
tempcount = 0
 
Do
    tempcount = tempcount + 1
    If Sheets(cursht).Cells(1, tempcount) <> "" Then
        testcount = testcount + 1
    Else
        Sheets(cursht).Columns(tempcount).Delete
        emptycount = emptycount + 1
        tempcount = tempcount - 1
    End If
Loop Until emptycount = 30

Currently I have to copy/paste and change the Sheet Name?  I want a simple loop, indexing my sheets, where I can perform the same operations. Any help is appreciated.

What do you mean by "indexer"?  Could you also have a read of [ASK] and [MCVE] please?  If I try your code on a blank sheet it returns an error - as tempcount will equal 0 after your Do....Loop and it can't do anything with Sheets(cursht).Columns(tempcount - 1).Copy as column -1 can't exist.

Also qccolcnt will always equal 0 when it's first used and you can't have Sheets(1).Columns(qccolcnt) which is the same as writing Sheets(1).Columns(0)

I don't think I quite understand what you are trying to do, but looping thru every sheet in a workbook is quite easy.  You can do it with the following code:
Sub LoopThroughSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Perform your operation here
        ' ws.Range("A1").Value = "Hello, World!"
    Next ws
End Sub


I would like to perform operations on cosecutive groups of sheets in a workbook. For example:  I have 100 sheets, all with unique names.  The first group I want to work on starts with sheet 10 and the sheet is named X1.  I want to perform operations on this sheet and the next seven.  Similarly, the next group starts at sheet 40 and this sheet is named Y1, and like before, I want to perform operations on the next seven, etc. Any help is appreciated.

@JohnSheehan - please update your question and make it easier to understand.

How can I indicate which sheet to start from? Sheet name, sheet location?

With the code below, the following occurs in a loop:

Get worksheet.
Extract the first letter of the worksheet name to determine the
group it belongs to.
Execute the correct set of operations based on the group
classification of the worksheet. (Which you will have to define).

Code:
Public Sub ExecuteOperations()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim SheetGroup As String

    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        SheetGroup = Left(Sheet.Name, 1)

        Select Case SheetGroup
            Case "X": ExecuteXOperation Sheet
            Case "Y": ExecuteYOperation Sheet
        End Select
    Next Sheet
End Sub

Private Sub ExecuteXOperation(Sheet As Worksheet)
    'Define x operations here.
End Sub

Private Sub ExecuteYOperation(Sheet As Worksheet)
    'Define y operations here.
End Sub

Hopefully this helps.

Muchas gracias.

You're welcome.  If my response solved your problem, please remember to mark my comment as the answer to your question :)
